# Comparing 2 2D char arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have two 2D char arrays a "large" and a "small" and want to find where the smaller one is located in the larger one.

Example:

the larger is

```
jfbsvdfaakjdfb
dsvkfvwaaksghd
aadkfghsgkdldl
aakdfghfgbkjbb
fdkbaadfkgaskj
```

and the smaller is

```
aa
aa
```

It would be located at [0, 7] and [2,0]

I'm wondering what would be the easiest way to compare the two? Right now, I'm thinking of for loops which at first compare the first elements of the array and if they don't match go until there is a match then once there is, more for loops which compare each element to see if they match. The other option was setting up HashMaps, but I'm not certain how that would be set up or use them to get results.

Upon tinkering with one of the suggestions, I came up with this code:
public static int[] findWaldo(char [][] large, char [][] small) {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char i [][] = new char[][]{
            {'d', 's', 'l', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 'e', 'i', 'j', 'a', 's', 'l', 'd', 'k', 'j'},
            {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'W', 'w', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'W', '1', 'l', 'k'},
            {'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'Z', 'A', 'a', 'Z', 'a', 'Z', '2', 'i', 'n'},
            {'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'Z', 'Z', 'L', 'l', 'Z', 'Z', '3', 'i', 'v'},
            {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', 'Z', 'd', 'Z', 'D', 'd', 'Z', '4', 'q', 'i'},
            {'3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'o', 'Z', 'Z', 'o', 'O', 'Z', '5', 'b', 'v'},
            {'k', 'e', '8', '7', '8', '4', 'j', 'f', 'l', 'k', 'a', 'v', '8', '8', 'h', 'j'}
    };

    char w [][] = new char[][]{
            {'W', 'w', '.', '.', '.', 'W', '1'},
            {'.', 'A', 'a', '.', 'a', '.', '2'},
            {'.', '.', 'L', 'l', '.', '.', '3'},
            {'.', 'd', '.', 'D', 'd', '.', '4'},
            {'o', '.', '.', 'o', 'O', '.', '5'}
    };

    find(i, w);
}

    public static int[] find(char [][] image, char [][] waldo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < waldo.length; i++) {
        char[] largerCharArray= large[i];
        String largerString = new String(largerCharArray);

        //used for debug purposes
        char[] array = largerCharArray;

        char [] smallCharArray = small[i];
        String smallString = new String(smallCharArray);

        char[] array1 = smallCharArray;

        System.out.println(largerString.indexOf(smallString));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    }

    return null;
}
```

All this code does is print the first part of the larger array, is there a reason for this?(Please ignore the .'s in the small array because those will then represent any char so it's essentially a match.

Comment: As opposed to figuring out what the easiest way would be, perhaps you should just make an attempt and then ask if any improvements can be made.

Comment: Implement what you have in mind and get back with problems that you face.

Comment: For each (x, y) bounded by [0 <= x <= largeWidth - smallWidth] and [0 <= y <= largeHeight - smallHeight], if for each (i, j) bounded by [x <= i <=  x + smallWidth] and [y <= j <= y + smallHeight], if they are equivalent for respective indices: you have a match at (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

An easy implementation would but just convert them to a String. Strings are a wonderful object to represent a character array! They have the added benefit of great methods that do this kind of stuff built in.

```
char[] largerCharArray= {'j','f','b'/*and so on...*/};
String largerString = new String(largerCharArray);
// or largerString = "jfbsvdfaakjdfb";

char [] smallCharArray = {'a', 'a'};
String smallString = new String(smallCharArray);
// or smallString = "aa";

System.out.println(largerString.indexOf(smallString));
```

Comment: Can the same concept be implemented for 2D arrays? I tried assigning it over and kept getting errors.

Comment: @user2449907 sure why not, a string is just an array of characters. So for a 2d array you could have String[].